# Catching all pyodbc excpetions

Tags: python, pyodbc

I have a script that is taking in queries from a config file.  Then running them and producing a report.
If one of the queries fails, I want to just skip it and still do the rest.

So I am using Try/Except.  Only I couldn't find a way to catch any exception from pyodbc.  I had to use except Exception.  And I know that is bad.  Is there a simple way to catch any exception that is from pyodbc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found [this wiki page](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Exceptions) regarding exceptions raised by pyodbc.

"DatabaseError" should cover any exception raised by the module

Comment: Very nice.  Thanks...   except pyodbc.DatabaseError  worked for the exceptions I have seen so far.